# What is the correct type annotation for a function that returns a Sequence of the same type as one of its inputs?

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

For the Python code

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence, Iterator

S = TypeVar("S", bound=Sequence)

def chunk(data: S) -> S:
    return data[:]
```

mypy 0.971 reports the error

> simple_8.py:6:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Sequence[Any]", expected "S")  [return-value]

Where is the type annotation error in this example and what is the correct, precise way to annotate this function?

Comment: Shouldn't the `TypeVar` be the generic type _in_ the `Sequence`? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=4ffe2c04ed081ce2cd3472fda5a60df2

Comment: Hmm.  Possibly.  However, the motivation for `S` was to declare that the return type is the same as the parameter type.  It's not just that they're both sequences but if one is str, the other is str, etc.

Comment: That's not what the `Sequence` interface declares, though. The result of calling `__getitem__` with a slice has to also be a sequence of the same type of elements, but not necessarily the same _type of sequence_. See https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/2c534dc2208191dc1ae1a6f51554fa5022cbfa0a/stdlib/typing.pyi#L463-L465

Comment: As far as i know, there is no such thing

Comment: Now I'm confused about something else ... There is a `Sequence` in typeshed _and_ typing _and_ collections.abc?  Which one does `from typing import Sequence` mean?  (I guess you're implying it means the one from typeshed...)

Comment: Both `collections.abc` and `typing` exist in both the **implementation** (CPython) and the **declarations** (Typeshed). In fact CPython imports `Sequence` into `typing` from `collections.abc` whereas Typeshed imports it into `collections.abc` from `typing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the Typeshed definition of `Sequence`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/2c534dc2208191dc1ae1a6f51554fa5022cbfa0a/stdlib/typing.pyi#L459-L465):

```
class Sequence(Collection[_T_co], Reversible[_T_co], Generic[_T_co]):
    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> _T_co: ...
    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, index: slice) -> Sequence[_T_co]: ...
```

you can see that `seq[:]` is guaranteed to return *some* `Sequence` with the same generic type `_T_Co` as the source, but that it's **not** necessarily the same type of sequence. Although the built-in sequence types generally have this behaviour, e.g. [for `list`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/2c534dc2208191dc1ae1a6f51554fa5022cbfa0a/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L991-L992):

```
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, __s: slice) -> list[_T]: ...
                                       # ^ concrete list not abstract Sequence
```

it's not a requirement of the interface.

As you don't supply the generic type to the `Sequence` in your `TypeVar`, it's the default `Any`, hence the error:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Sequence[Any]", expected "S") [return-value]
```

The slice `data[:]` gives a `Sequence[Any]`, which *might* be the same as `S` but is not *required* to be. So if you want to support any `Sequence`, the most precise you can be is:

```py
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def chunk(data: Sequence[T]) -> Sequence[T]:
    return data[:]
```

[Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=4ffe2c04ed081ce2cd3472fda5a60df2)

---

Alternatively, if you define a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) with the stricter typing that `seq[:]` *must* return the same type:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class StrictSlice(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self: T, index: slice) -> T: ...
```

you can then use this as the `bound` type in `S` and get the type-preserving behaviour:

```
S = TypeVar("S", bound=StrictSlice)

def chunk(data: S) -> S:
    return data[:]

l: list[int] = chunk([1, 2, 3])
s: str = chunk("Hello, world!")
```

If you tried this with the `Sequence[T]`, you'd get e.g. `expression has type "Sequence[int]", variable has type "List[int]"`.

[Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=29b736f9408588d634069032db77c592)